# Functional Analysis, Sequence of continuous linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let {${\phi_n}$}$_{n=1}$ be sequence of continuous linear functionals $ X \to K $ on a Banach Space $X$ such that {$\phi_n(x)$}$_{n=1}$ is convergent for every $ x \in X$ . Show that the sequence {$\phi_n(x_n)$}$_{n=1}$ is convergent whenever {$x_n$}$_{n=1}$ is convergent in $X$.

Comment: What does the condition that $\phi_n(x)$ converges for all $x$ tell you about the sequence $(\phi_n)$?

Comment: I edited my question, and question just has those conditions. Thank you. @DanielFischer

Comment: I think Daniel was trying to ask you whether you were able to conclude anything about the sequence $(\phi_n)$ based on the condition he mentioned.  He wasn't asking for clarification.

Comment: It seems like I completely missunderstood him. However, This subject is quite new for me. So I need more explaination :/ @JoshKeneda

Comment: Have you covered some big consequences of the Baire category theorem?  Like the uniform boundedness principle or open mapping theorem?  One of those will be useful in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $K$ is either $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$. Let $x\in X$ be the limit of $x_{n}$ and let $k\in K$ be the limit of $\phi_{n}(x)$. We want to prove that $k$ is the limit of $\phi_{n}(x_{n})$.

We have:

\begin{align*}
&\vert\phi_{n}(x_{n})-k\vert \\
&= \vert\phi_{n}(x_{n})-\phi_{n}(x)+\phi_{n}(x)-k\vert\\
&\le \vert \phi_{n}(x_{n})-\phi_{n}(x)\vert+\vert \phi_{n}(x)-k\vert \tag{triangle inequality in $K$}\\
&= \vert\phi_{n}(x_{n}-x)\vert+\vert\phi_{n}(x)-k\vert \tag{as $\phi_{n}$ are linear functionals}\\
&\le \Vert\phi_{n}\Vert\cdot\Vert x_{n}-x\Vert_{X}+\vert \phi_{n}(x)-k\vert \tag{as $\phi_{n}$ are linear maps on $X$}
\end{align*}

Note that for any $n$, $\Vert\phi_{n}\Vert<\infty$ since the $\phi_{n}$ are continuous. Thus, as $x_{n}\to x$ and $\phi_{n}(x)\to k$ by construction, we only need to prove that there exists a bound $M$ independent on $n$ such that $\Vert\phi_{n}\Vert\le M$.

But this is a consequence of the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), which we can apply because we have the appropriate hypothesis.

Indeed, the fact that $\phi_{n}(x)$ converges to some $k_{x}$ for any $x\in X$ directly implies that $\sup_{n}\vert\phi_{n}(x)\vert<\infty$: fix $\epsilon>0$. There exists $N_{\epsilon}$ such that for any $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$, we have $\vert\phi_{n}(x)\vert\le \epsilon+\vert k_{x}\vert$, and thus $\sup_{n}\vert\phi_{n}(x)\vert\le\max\{\vert\phi_{N}(x)\vert,\epsilon+\vert k_{x}\vert\,:\, N< N_{\epsilon}\}$.